# transferring the public key certificate from one client application to another

Tags: java, https

I have a java application that is deployed on multiple servers that work in a load-balancing mode.
More nodes can be added to handle more load.

The application communicates with an external web server over https. The self-signed public key certificate of the server is different for each customer and is manually imported by each customer in the trust-store.

It is now required that whenever a new application node is added to the set-up, the certificate should be auto-imported on startup.

My application is such that whenever a new node is added to the set-up, the existing nodes get a notification(kafka based).

I am new to the https protocol and looking for the best possible way in which the new node can be made to auto-import all the certificate(s) that have been manually imported in the existing nodes' truststore. Any ideas?

Comment: If the architecture is built on Kafka, you could probably emit an event on each new certificate import request. Then you would need a piece of logic responsible for adding the certificate to the trust-store. Every new node would replay all the events against its own storage.

Comment: @yegodm, do you mean this: On getting notified of a new node, the existing nodes read their trust-store & transmit(via kafka) all the certificates to the newly added node. The newly added node receives the certs & adds them to its (blank) truststore?

Comment: It's probably one way to do that. Another approach is to make sure that a new certificate is added programatically. Then an event in Kafka would cause all of the nodes to add the new certificate to their respective stores. A new node would replay all the events and get its store in-sync with the rest.